# Reduce pseudocode font size (not global)

Tags: beamer, fontsize, algorithms

In this [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26539/beamer-and-pseudocode) I would like to reduce the pseudocode font size, but only for this slide while keeping the others in the default font size. How can I do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, or `\tiny` immediately after the beginning of the `algorithm` environment. This changes the size of *everything* inside the environment (except for the caption), and nowhere else.

**Edited to add:** This will apparently leave the size of the line-numbers and of the caption unchanged. In order to change the size of the line-numbers for the algorithm, add the command `\algsetup{linenosize=<size>}` just inside the `algorithm` environment, where `<size>` is again something like `\small`, `\footnotesize`, *etc.* Note that the default is to have line-numbers somewhat smaller than the surrounding text: if you want the appearance to be somewhat similar to algorithms elsewhere in your document, you should also choose a smaller size for the line-numbers than the algorithm body.

I am not sure how best to modify the size of the caption, unfortunately.

**Example document.**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithmic,algorithm2e,float}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \algsetup{linenosize=\tiny}
  \scriptsize
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \FOR{this algorithm only}
      \STATE all of the text in a smaller size of typeface
    \ENDFOR
    \medskip
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{an algorithm with smaller typeface}
\end{algorithm}

\bigskip

some text outside of the environment

\bigskip

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \FOR{all other algorithms}
      \STATE everything normally unless otherwise modified
    \ENDFOR
    \medskip
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{an algorithm with normal typeface}
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Result.**

[image: Algorithms with different sizes of typeface]

Comment: great! last question, how can we change the caption text size?

Comment: @flow: Unfortunately, I can't figure out a graceful way to do so. I just found out that my original answer also did not modify the size of the line-numbers: I've revised my answer to describe how to do that, at least.

Comment: To change the caption put `\renewcommand{\AlCapSty}[1]{\normalfont\scriptsize{\textbf{#1}}\unskip}` in the environment.

Comment: A follow-up question on the line no size. Thanks a lot. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145932/reduce-the-line-number-font-size-of-pseudocode

Comment: I am having `! Undefined control sequence for \algsetup                  {linenosize=\small}` how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9):

`algorithm2e` provides commands for customizing pseudocode font shape and size, `algorithmic` does that for line numbering. For example:

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\SetAlFnt{\small}
\SetAlCapFnt{\large}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\large}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\algsetup{linenosize=\tiny}
```

Comment: Curious. When I compile this with a simple example, I get `Undefined control sequence: \SetAlCapNameFnt`, even though the command is clearly mentioned in the `algorithm2e` documentation.

Comment: @Niel: perhaps update the package.

Comment: just did, still have the problem. Quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering a part of question, rest are already answered.

To reduce the size of caption just use the `\small` or `\tiny` inside the caption i.e., `\caption{<here> your_caption}`. For e.g., `\caption{\tiny My Algorithm}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Thanks for your answer. However, your solution was already proposed. If you allow me a suggestion, it may be a good idea to check answers already given, first ;-) // See you next time.