# Reduce the line number font size of pseudocode?

Tags: fontsize, algorithms, algorithmicx, pseudocode

I have learned from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26569/31917) on how to reduce the font size in the pseudocode.

The last thing left for me is to reduce the line number font size as well. The following is my MWE, and it seems that `\algsetup{linenosize=\tiny}` is not working.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\algsetup{linenosize=\tiny}
\small %\small, \footnotesize, \scriptsize, or \tiny
\caption{a}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{a}{}
    \While{aa}
        \State aa
    \EndWhile
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\label{alg:drs}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can redefine the `\alglinenumber` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode} % http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\algrenewcommand\alglinenumber[1]{\tiny #1:}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{a}\label{alg:drs}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{a}{}
    \While{aa}
      \State aa
    \EndWhile
  \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```